# SQL Error inccorect integer and notice - undefined index

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem and I don't know why.
When I try to save form I get this:

> Notice: Undefined index: id_prod in C:\wamp64\www\mgn\addc.php on line
>   9 Error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id_prod' at row 1

```
    $adds['id_prod'] = $cnx->real_escape_string($_POST["id_prod"]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `zzz` (ssn, date, id_prod) VALUES ('". $adds['ssn']. "', '". $adds['date']. "', '". $adds['id_prod']. "')";

<body>
   <form action="addc.php">
         <table>
           <tr>
             <td>SSN:</td>

           <td><input type="text" name="ssn"></td>
             </select>
             </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Date</td>
             <td><input type= "date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" name="date"  /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Prod</td>
     <td><select name="combo" id="combo">
             </select>
             </td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="addc"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
</body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number - you probably have a string - and can type a letter in numeric data in you form - probably the SSN. You should Google "casting variables" to get a feel for what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't have any field with the name `id_prod` in the sample code you give here, so this variable can't exists. You need to rename one or add this missing field.

Then, you need to add `method="post"` to your `<form>` tag like this :

```
<form action="addc.php" method="post">
```

Without it, it will send data using `GET` and you'll need to handle them with `$_GET['id_prod']`.

You can add a name to your submit button and test if this variable exists before using `$_POST` variable to prevent using undefined variables, like this :

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="submit" id="addc" name="submit">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // your code
}
?>
```

This will resolve the notice `Undefined index: id_prod` and error after that.

Comment: I already tried with isset, but: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp64\www\mgn\addc.php on line 2

Comment: Sorry, typo, it was missing a `)` ;)

Comment: You don't have any field with the name `id_prod` so it can't exists. You need to put the correct name in your `$_POST` variable or rename a field's name with `id_prod`